# Is there any country outside the EU that prohibits using artificial intelligence software for mass surveillance or ranking social behavior?

Tags: law, technology, surveillance

According to *The Diplomat*, China is [already exporting its Social Credit System](https://thediplomat.com/2020/01/exporting-chinas-social-credit-system-to-central-asia/), or at least intending to:

> In 2020, China will conduct a feasibility run for social credit system
> in Kazakhstan, Kyrgyzstan and Mongolia,
> (..)
> Many countries, also with weak legal systems, share similar
> experiences with China and find Beijing’s promised automated model of
> policing appealing. Branded as “safe cities,” networks of Chinese
> surveillance cameras form the foundation of the social credit system,
> and they are already emerging all over the world, including in Central
> Asia. The Chinese government almost exclusively emphasizes the
> benefits of these camera networks for traffic monitoring.

In the meantime, EU considered [banning using artificial intelligence software for mass surveillance and ranking social behavior](https://www.cnbc.com/2021/04/15/eu-considers-ban-on-ai-for-mass-surveillance-social-credit-scores.html).

Is there any other government that considers or already prohibited AI software in this way?

Comment: Are you talking specifically about laws against AI? Australia and Canada have [used existing privacy legislation](https://techcrunch.com/2021/11/03/clearview-ai-australia-privacy-breach/) to restrict AI surveillance.

Comment: @StuartF Yes, that article seems to provide relevant examples.